# SED Modify only submatch in file

Tags: regex, sed

I have this:

```
sed -i "s/PID:\([0-9]*\)/PID:${$}/" "${ARCHIVO_INFO_SESION}"
```

Which would modify PID saved in a text file after `PID:` word.

My question is if its possible to refer only to the submatch between the `( )` instead of having to write again `PID:` in the replacemente part, example:

```
sed -i "s/PID:\([0-9]*\)/\1${$}/" "${ARCHIVO_INFO_SESION}"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
sed "s/\(PID:\)[0-9]*/\1${$}/" "${ARCHIVO_INFO_SESION}"
```

hope this helps,

Comment: Mmmmm inverting the selection could be a good idea, I'll use it. Thanks.